# JavaScript Bookmarklet to open new Window and transmit params of origin Page

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I have a perfectly working bookmarklet to grab the Document-Title and the URL of the current Website and place it into the URL of the new loaded Page (Code below) … now I wonder how to let this domain.com/bookmarklet?… open in a new small window (600x600px), so that I still see the old website from where I grabed the title and url in the background and have the new page (domain.com/bookmarklet?…) in the foreground.

```
javascript:location.href='http://domain.com/bookmarklet?url='+encodeURIComponent(location.href)+';title='+encodeURIComponent(document.title)
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`window.open(...)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.open) instead of setting `location.href = ...`.

Comment: thx … but because of the encodeURIComponent etc. how can I use size-params like 'width=600,height=600' ?

Comment: Read the docs I linked. Use the `strWindowFeatures` argument.

Comment: yeah I saw that, but http://jsfiddle.net/5zd3n/ the sizes do not work … maybe because of the many quotes?

Comment: You're passing those arguments as the `strWindowTitle`.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use [window.open()](http://www.javascript-coder.com/window-popup/javascript-window-open.phtml) for that

```
javascript:window.open ("http://domain.com/bookmarklet?.......","MyBookmarklet");
```

Comment: You don't have to give new windows a name, but if you do, **don't** use names with spaces in them (as that breaks in Internet Explorer).

Comment: thx … but because of the encodeURIComponent etc. I can't use the name and size settings, right?